# 'org.openide.util.NbBundle' causing problems

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

I have just tried to incorporate a NetBeans project into an Eclipse one (javaSE-1.6). There are differences between the 2 IDEs however. Overall, im trying to implement the scanning of QRcodes via a webcam. All i got was nullpointer exceptions & I suspect it is caused by the following code. Basically i have 3 JLabels & a button. How can I do a workaround to make it work, without using 'org.openide.util.NbBundle'?

```
        JLabel scannerScreen = new JLabel("connecting to camera");
        scannerScreen.setBounds(72, 50, 274, 205);
        //suspected erroneous code at following line
        //org.openide.awt.Mnemonics.setLocalizedText(scannerScreen, org.openide.util.NbBundle.getMessage(ScannerUI.class, "ScannerPanel.scannerScreen.text")); // NOI18N
        panel.add(scannerScreen);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Welcome ");
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(72, 11, 274, 58);
        panel.add(lblNewLabel_1);       

        //suspected erroneous code at following line
        //org.openide.awt.Mnemonics.setLocalizedText(nextScan, org.openide.util.NbBundle.getMessage(ScannerUI.class, "ScannerPanel.nextScan.text")); // NOI18N
        JButton nextScan = new JButton("Next Scan");
        nextScan.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
            {
                nextScanActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        nextScan.setBounds(72, 266, 89, 23);        
        panel.add(nextScan);
```

Comment: `org.openide.util.NbBundle` is a class from the NetBeans *platform* and is only available when you build your application based on that platform. There *might* be ways to extract that part from the NetBeans platform to be used in generic Java/Swing application but I doubt it's worth the effort - and you'll probably need to extract loads of other base functionality from the NetBeans platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are are trying to convert a form from a NB plaform application/module ?

Give it a try:

- open the form in NetBeans GUI Builder
- in the navigator open the properties of the top most item
- uncheck "Generate mnemonics code" [image]
- make a simple change in the form
- save the form
- look at the sources - the generated code regarding mnemonics should be gone